# Postgres SELECT statement where field value ends with

Tags: postgresql, select, where-clause

I have a postgres database table called: web_data

Currently i'm running the following SQL select statement:

```
SELECT url_path FROM web_data WHERE url_path IS NOT NULL
```

Here are some example results I will get for url_path:

```
/
/aboutus.html
/services.php
/images/twitter_counter.png
/images/facebook_counter.png
/mobile/windows/TileTemplate.xml
/en_US/fbevents.js
/css/style.css
```

I would like to return results where the end value of url_path is either one of the following:

```
/
.html
.htm
.php
.asp
.aspx
.pdf
```

Is there a way to put this into the SQL statement instead of getting all results and then going through it with something like PHP?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use the `LIKE` operator:

```
select url_path
from web_data
where url_path like '%.htm'
   or url_path like '%.html'
   or url_path like '%.php'
   or url_path like '%.asp'
   or url_path like '%.aspx'
   or url_path like '%.pdf'
   or url_path like '%/';
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE

Comment: so having the % only in the beginning mean it has to end like that? because with the LIKE syntax i usually put LIKE %.html% Also, if i have lots of records, is the LIKE function very slow?

Comment: @Ahmed: `%` is a wildcard `%.html` means any value that _ends_ with `.html`. And yes this is going to be slow because the database can't use a regluar index for that. You would need to create a [trigram](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html) index if you really have that many rows so that an index would help

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SIMILAR TO` to match your end values.

```
SELECT 
  url_path 
FROM 
  web_data 
WHERE 
  url_path SIMILAR TO '%(.htm|.html|.php|.asp|.aspx|.pdf|/)';
```

This is actually rewritten to following regex match:

```
SELECT 
  url_path 
FROM 
  web_data 
WHERE 
  url_path ~ '(.htm|.html|.php|.asp|.aspx|.pdf|/)$';
```

Thus regex match is more performant then `SIMILAR TO` and you can use this one.